# Make search block appear for anonymous user

Tags: 7, blocks, search

I have defined a region in my theme in which I've placed the search box. But, it only appears when a user is logged in. I checked to see the visibility and made sure the block is also visible to anonymous users; but it doesn't show up.
I searched online for the issue but I wasn't able to find a good (working) solution. Is there a way to do so?

My search block visibility settings:
[image: snap]

Comment: Did you assign a region to the block?

Comment: yes I did. It appears fine for other roles. Just doesn't show up for an anonymous user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you and I had the same problem; the fix "Under Search give 'Use search ' permission for anonymous user" actually worked for me, but because of this, it didn't work immediately:

Home » Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance

"Cache pages for anonymous users"

just hit "Clear all cache" & your good to go!

Answer (score 3):

There is one more permission need to set at admin/people/permissions. Under Search give  'Use search ' permission for anonymous user

Comment: I did that too before posting the question, but still no luck :-/

Comment: Try disabling CSS/JS, Clear your cache and hope for the best

Comment: @saadlulu I've turned CSS/JS caching off, and also did `drush cc all` and cleared even by browser's cache. Still not working.

Comment: Is your site live? can I visit it as anonymous user?